# Why i get errors 404/415 in angular?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

Please help me find a solution to the problem. Neither I nor my friend found anything worthwhile.

The original code (produces 404):

```
     //client
    private url = "https://localhost:44315/api/values";
 
    deleteMessage(id: number) {
        return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id);
    }

     //controller asp
    [HttpDelete("api/values/{messageId}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
         if (_messager.GetMessageById(id) != null)
         {
            _messager.DeleteMessage(id);
            return Ok();
         }
         return NotFound();
    }
```

Later, the function was rewritten (now produces 405):

```
 deleteMessage(id: number) {
        return this.http.delete(this.url + '?id=' + id);
    }
```

Also, there is a problem, the server gets null, not a string. If you pass the "Message" object, then it works. If I add the [frombody] attribute to the code with string, then I get an error 415.

Error on the client, the swagger UI works correctly. Tell me what's wrong.

```
createMessage(message: Message) {
     return this.http.post(this.url, message.msg);
    }

 //public IActionResult Add([FromBody] MessageModel message)
        public IActionResult Add(string message)
        {
            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
          //  {
                _messager.AddMessage(message);
                return Ok(message);
         //   }
         //   return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
```

Comment: Your routing attribute specifies that the param name should be `messageId` but the actual parameter name on the action is `id`. You should change the route attribute to `[HttpDelete("api/values/{id}")]`

Comment: @phuzi this doesn't change anything

Comment: Which version of the methode `deleteMessage`are you using now? The routing does not check for querystring the id needs to be part of path.

Comment: @Thomas Ranger  first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should stringify the data, and set the http header `content-type` as `"application/json"`

```
this.http
  .post(this.url, JSON.stringify(message.msg), {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" })
  })
```

Then add [FromBody] attribute to the string parameter.

```
    public IActionResult Add([FromBody]string message)
    {
        //if (ModelState.IsValid)
        //{
              _messager.AddMessage(message);
              return Ok(message);
        //}
        //return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the data is being added to the database, but I get the error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad text: "ghghgh"